# Laravel echo connects to pusher instead of laravel-websockets

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, pusher

I start laravel-websockets as a systemctl service.

Everything works but after I do a `sudo reboot` until the laravel-websockets process starts (I am using [nginx](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/ssl#usage-with-a-reverse-proxy-like-nginx) as a reverse proxy too) the clients on the app are connecting to pusher instead of my socket service.

If I clear the cookies and refresh the page (a few minutes after the machine and all services started) the clients are connecting as they should to the laravel-websockets. But only if I clear the cookies. No matter how many times I refresh the page the client is still connecting to pusher if I don't clear the cookies.

In the dev tools network tab:
`https://sockjs-eu.pusher.com/pusher/app/....`
instead of
`https://socket.mydomain.com`

In my pusher app I have client events turned off. But in laravel websockets I have them on. I know for sure the clients are connecting to pusher because I get this in the error console:
`To send client events, you must enable this feature in the Settings page of your dashboard.`

I am starting laravel queue worker as a systemctl service too. Might this have anything to do with it? Should they start in a order or something?

**EDIT**

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'pusher',
     key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
     cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
     wsHost: 'socket.mydomain.com', //this is not the real domain
     wssHost: 'socket.mydomain.com', //this is not the real domain
     wssPort:443,
     forceTLS: true,
     disableStats: true,
 });
```

Comment: can you add your code `new Echo({})` ?

Comment: @Kamlesh Paul I added it in edit. I only changed the domain I don't want to make it public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this config

```js
window.Echo = new Echo({
     broadcaster: 'pusher',
     key: 'broadcasting', // hard code
     wsHost: window.location.hostname,
     wssHost: window.location.hostname, 
     enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
     wssPort:443,
     forceTLS: true,
     disableStats: true,
 });
```

here `key: 'broadcasting'` make it hard code and try some time it create issue this is my config may it helps you

Comment: Yeah you are on to something. I was using correct pusher key and before the laravel websockets would start it would aready try to connect to pusher instead. I changed the .env key and secret to something random and now it works. Thank you. They should have mentioned in the documentation somewhere that you don't need the correct pusher credentials.